# Nav "Back" button pause in order to do a quick animation before pop

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a navigation controller and a scroll view inside it.

When the user hits the "Back" button I would like to animate the scroll view to offset 0, 0 before the view "pop" transition begins.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`UINavigationBarDelegate` is the delegate class and it implements `-navigationBar:shouldPopItem`. Try putting your animation code in there.

Alternately, you can try this

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
       // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
       // in the navigation stack.  Put animation code here
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: I did try that and you only see the transition of the nave controller. When you enter the view again the content is scrolled at 0, 0. So some way of deferring the "back" operation is needed or something else.

Comment: Now with viewWillDisappear it is improved, both animations start at the same time. Let me try shouldPopItem...

Comment: @vgr: I'm curious to know which method works better. Please post back once you've tried out `shouldPopItem`.

Comment: Will do. Investigating why I can't get shouldPopItem to work. It never gets called from within a UIViewController. I do set the delegate in init like this "        self.navigationController.navigationBar.delegate = self;"